# Disable Excel Data Connections when no connection to the database

Tags: microsoft-excel, sql-server

Is it possible to pause/disable Excel data connection on a macro?

I don't want to remove the data connections, I would just like to create an option to disable them if the user can't connect to our central database.

Comment: Is the Security message poping up and bothering the user? or is there another reason you want to do the above?

Comment: @NetworkKingPin It is bothering the user. The sheet has several drop down boxes and each time one is changed the parameter value is passed to SQL causing the error to appear.